# how we can loop on a list of columns to apply a pyspark sql query on each of them

Tags: sql, pyspark

This is the code i used in order to loop on the list of columns:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PZnK.png)
But it gave me the following error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ7Dy.png)

I did the same on another query but it gives me a synthax error too:

the error that gives :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie1HP.png)

The code looks fine so i can't tell where the problem is

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms and also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use SQL directly in select, instead do this,

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('DATA')

col_list = [<enter column names here>]

for i in col_list:
    sql_query = spark.sql(f"select * from data where {i} is null")
    sql_query.show()
```

or you can also do this,

```
for i in col_list:
    df.filter(F.col(i).isNull()).show()
```